# Android BroadcastReceiver: run it on default process or in a new one?

Tags: android, process, receiver

I have an application with two Broadcast Receivers, one of them to receive data and the other one to send it. I've seen that they have an attribute android:process to make them run on the application's default process or in another one. In the examples I found using google, receivers were set to run in the process ":remote".

My question is, what are the advantages and disadvantages of using each option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a different Process than the Default Process of the Application is handy when you want to share ressources with another Application.

Todo so you need to arrange two Applications with the same processname, if your processname begins with an lowerchar a global process is spawned. If it begins with a colon : than the process is private.
Keep in mind that to share a process between two apps you need the same userID and the same app certificate.

You also have to load ressources only once and get benefits in memory consumption.

for [more information](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#proc)

Answer (score 0):

A process has its own main thread. So, when using different processes i.e. `:remote`, then it means the code defined in that process will run on a separate thread. You don't usually need to do this for an ordinary workflow.